# got error access sqlite from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, fragment

I've got following error when I take asyntake from Fragment and access to sqlite as follow.

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)

and here is my coding. I don't know why I got this error even though I've already declare **"DatabaseUtil dbUtil = new DatabaseUtil(ctx);"**

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        .
        ..

    }



    public static class ContentFragment extends Fragment {


        public ContentFragment() {

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, container, false);
            MainActivity myActivity = new MainActivity();
            MainActivity.GetDataTask asyncTask = myActivity.new GetDataTask(); 

            return rootView;
        }
    }    

    private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Integer> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }       

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Object... args) {

            DatabaseUtil dbUtil = new DatabaseUtil(ctx);
                dbUtil.open();
                        dbUtil.insertRecord(....);
                dbUtil.close();

            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is your asynctask defined in activity or framgent.? i suggest you do it in fragment and remove this `MainActivity myActivity = new MainActivity()`

Comment: Defined means?? All of these asynctask and ContentFragment are under Activity. I've a bit changed my coding. Please check it.

Comment: i see many things wrong in your code. is asynctask an inner class of your fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make Constructor for **GetDataTask**....

```
Context ctx;

public GetDataTask(Context c){

 this.ctx = c;

}
```

Now you can use this **ctx** variable

```
DatabaseUtil dbUtil = new DatabaseUtil(ctx);
```

Comment: @ppshein Also check this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/1aPZXZG6kWk. if you need a acitivty context inside a static inner class you must have weakreference to it or it might lead to memory leak.CheckRomain Guy's answer. scroll down and check the last few points here http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is wrong

```
    MainActivity myActivity = new MainActivity();
```

You are creating an instance of activity class. Activity is started by `startActivtiy(new Intent(params))`. Activity has ui and lifecycle. So creating an instance od activity class is not needed.

Suggest have the asynctask in your fragment class

Also

```
   DatabaseUtil dbUtil = new DatabaseUtil(getActivtiy());
```

To the edited question

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    .
    ..

  }
```

Then in ContentFragment.java

```
    public class ContentFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, container, false);
         new GetDataTask(getActivity()).execute(params);
        return rootView;
    }
}    

 class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Integer> {

    Context mContext;  
   public GetDataTask(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mContext = activity;
}

    @Override 
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }       

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Object... args) {

        DatabaseUtil dbUtil = new DatabaseUtil(mContext);
            dbUtil.open();
                    dbUtil.insertRecord(....);
            dbUtil.close();

        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry. It's my mistake. I've edited my coding. asynctask is an inner class of my fragment. How to correct?

Comment: then try `new GetDataTask().execute(lastrecordfromlocal, userdefined)` and remove this   `MainActivity myActivity = new MainActivity()`

Comment: when I try like that, get this error "No enclosing instance of type MainActivity is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type MainActivity (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of MainActivity)."

Comment: @ppshein have your fragment as separate not as inner class to avoid confusion

Comment: Please check again my coding. I've changed it again as full of code.

Comment: @ppshein move your fragment as a separate class. have your asynctask inside fragment. and use `getActivity()` to get the activity context. and keep the old post the same and put your edit under the edit section

Comment: when I did as you told "DatabaseUtil dbUtil = new DatabaseUtil(getActivity());" got this error "The method getActivity() is undefined for the type MainActivity.GetDataTask"

Comment: @ppshein have your fragment not as an inner class but as a separate class. check the edit

Comment: @ppshein check the edit now.pass the activity context using `getActivity()` to the constructor of asynctask and use the same for `DatabaseUtil dbUtil = new DatabaseUtil(mContext)`. Also have your fragment as a separate class.